# How to get animation to work again after complete?

Tags: android, animation

On button click I would like to make an image move either down or right. The issue I am running into is that the movement of the image only occurs once. In onClick() method I am just calling either one of my move methods. Here are the move methods.

```
private void moveLeftToRight() {
    animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 200.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    animation.setDuration(1500); // animation duration
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    iv1.startAnimation(animation); // start animation
}

private void moveUpToDown() {
    animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 200.0f);
    animation.setDuration(1500); // animation duration
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    iv1.startAnimation(animation); // start animation
}
```

I can call either one of these one time for the first time. Thereafter the animation methods do not work. I am wondering if I need to reset or something. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the coordinates passed to `TranslateAnimation()` relative or not? If they're not that's why.

Comment: They are not relative. I am just experimenting with moving an image around the screen. So I am just moving 200 pixels down or right. Is that an issue? I think I understand what you are saying though. In order for the image to continue from where it was moved I have to set up some coordinates that maps the current position of the image, so that it can move again. Correct?

Comment: I suspect in `moveLeftToRight()` you're moving to the coordinates {0, 200, 0, 0} (relative to {0,0} not the view), meaning sequential calls will animate the view to the exact same spot (thus not moving). To fix this get the view coordinates and add your values and then pass that to `TranslateAnimation`

Comment: Yes! That describes exactly what I am seeing. I had a misunderstanding, I thought (0, 200, 0, 0) were pixel movements, not coordinates. If these are coordinates, then what I am seeing and what you are saying makes perfect sense. Let me make a correction to my parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass your coordinates to `TranslateAnimation` those coordinates are relative to 0,0 and not the views coordinates.

To fix this we will get the views coordinates with `view.bottom`, `view.left` etc.

Then add the values you'd like to transform by to those values, pass those to `TranslateAnimation`, and your translation will work as expected.